# How to generate regional groups in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to Python and programming in general. I have posted a variation of this question before. I hope this time my presentation comes through somewhat better. I hope my formatting is par for the course.
This is the code that reads my csv file in:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np      
ef=pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/user/anaconda3/une_edu_pipc_03.csv')
pd.options.display.precision = 3
ef.head(5)
```

The data for 3085 counties are successfully read.
The key column is Stabr, the label standing for two-letter, capitalized, abbreviations of America's  fifty states.
My first order of business is get corral relevant data for these fifty states into eight regional groups: eg, ef_neng stand for New England.(There are seven other regional groups)  For this, I'm writing this code:

```
ef_neng=ef.loc[(ef["Stabr"]=="ME") & (ef["Stabr"]=="VT") & (ef["Stabr"]=="NH") & (ef["Stabr"]=="MA") & (ef["Stabr"]=="RI") \
                & (ef["Stabr"]=="CT")]
ef_neng.head(5)
```

ME stands for Maine, VT for Vermont, and so on. My understanding, which could be very poor, is that ef_neng would be a dataframe with shape of 3085 times 99.

This triggers the following output:

```
   0 rows × 99 columns
```

Why is this generating an empty dataframe, even though the code seems to me to be correct?

Comment: @thorntonc Thank you for editing my earlier post. I thought I had formatted the code correctly---turned out, I was incorrect.  Here is why I did: I used Notepad++. In order to correctly highlight my code input, should I have done each of the following three things: (1) hit the control+k; (2) create code fences above and beneath the code block; (3) indent the code by four spaces.  (These three to-do imperatives are suggested by the markdown-writing literature). I know I am missing and yet I'm failing to find out what I am missing.  Can you help by giving me a blow-by-blow narration. Be grateful

Comment: Is there a particular text editor I should read while preparing content to be posted to the SO? I have read a lot of the guidance on Markdown syntax.  That said, I am missing something subtle but mission-critical. Thank you all in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe because you are using an `&` for an AND between the values in the same column?

This means you are finding those rows, which have `ef["Stabr"]` value equal to "ME" and "VT" and "NH" and ..., at the same time which is not possible because a row can have only a single value out of them at a time. Therefore, it would return 0 rows.

It should be an OR condition which is done by `|` this operator. This will get you the rows where `ef["Stabr"]` value can be equal to "ME" or "VT" or "NH" or ... and so no.

Try this instead -

```
ef_neng=ef.loc[(ef["Stabr"]=="ME") | (ef["Stabr"]=="VT") | (ef["Stabr"]=="NH") | (ef["Stabr"]=="MA") | (ef["Stabr"]=="RI") \
                | (ef["Stabr"]=="CT")]
ef_neng.head(5)
```

If this is actually the case might I recommend using the `.isin()` operator for the same?

```
ef.loc[ef["Stabr"].isin(["ME", "VT", "NH"])] #add other choices here to the list
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  You are really spot on. SO is amazing!

Comment: Glad to help @NaeemChowdhury. Do mark the answer as right if it helped you for the sake of others who have similar issues.